# Jscrollpane center aligns when label is too small

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

This question is very similiar to this: [JScrollPane doesn't top align when there is more than enough space to show the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941320/jscrollpane-doesnt-top-align-when-there-is-more-than-enough-space-to-show-the-c) I tried this solution, but it does not work.

When I add a jlabel to jscrollpane, when the jlabel is small, the label becomes centered. It works normally when the scrollbar shows. Setting boxlayout does not change anything. I feel like this isn't working properly because I'm setting a perferred size to the panel? But if I remove the line `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(screenSize.width*0.7 - 50), screenSize.height-150));` The label becomes small when there is no text, and grows to accomdate text, which I don't want. If I add the panel instead of the label, it makes the screen scrollable even though there isn't text?

This is my code:

```java
public class Test {
    // JFrame 
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test"); 
    //panel 1
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    // label to display text 
    static JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
    //scroll panel in main method
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 20));
        label.setText("any text makes it centered beyond 40 lines");
        //create panel
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(screenSize.width*0.7 - 50), screenSize.height-150));
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 10));
        
        JScrollPane jspanel = new JScrollPane(label, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        //jspanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jspanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(screenSize.width*0.7 - 70), screenSize.height-180));
        jspanel.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
        jspanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        jspanel.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        jspanel.setAlignmentY(JScrollPane.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        //frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jspanel);
        frame.setSize((int)(screenSize.width*0.7), screenSize.height - 50);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.pack();  
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem. Your question is about displaying a label in a JScrollPane. The custom Font is irrelevant and should be removed. The custom ScrollBarUI is irrelevant and should be removed. First get the code working with standard classes to make sure the problem isn't with the custom classes. Other suggestions: 1) Don't use setPreferredSize(). Scrolling will NOT work when you hard code a size. 2) there is no need to use revalidate(). When you invoke pack() / setVisible() the layout manager will be invoked and components will be given a size/location.

Comment: So is the setPrefferredSize the problem? Scrolling works, but the label is at the center.

Comment: It is minimal reproducible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    jspanel.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    jspanel.setAlignmentY(JScrollPane.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
```

That will align the scrollpane in its parent container, depending on the layout manager being used. It does not affect the alignment of any component added to the scrollpane. It is not needed.

> the label becomes centered

The label is sized to fill the entire space available, so you need to customize how the text of the label is painted.

If you don't want it centered then you can place it at the top using:

```
label.setVerticalAlignment( SwingConstants.TOP );
```

Comment: Hum... I tried that, but it's still centered.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code from the MRE and added that single line of code and the text is displayed at the top/left of the scrollpane. Post your updated MRE.

Comment: Thanks, I found where I should have placed label.setVerticalAlignment, it works now. (I was too excited)

Answer (score 0):

After reworking your code, I came up with the following GUI.

[image: JScrollPane Test]

1. I added a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I eliminated all static references, except for the `main` method.
3. I reworked your code into methods so I could focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

Here's the complete runnable example.  This is a minimal reproducible example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class JScrollPaneTestGUI implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JScrollPaneTestGUI());
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScrollPane Test"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JScrollPane jspanel = createJScrollPane();
        frame.add(jspanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();  
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createJScrollPane() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 20));
        label.setText("any text makes it centered beyond 40 lines");
        //create panel
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JScrollPane jspanel = new JScrollPane(panel);
       
        return jspanel;
    }
    
}
```